# Is there any way we can debug to discover "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, widget

Building a JSONDecoder to get weather data to use in a widget, I'm facing this issue (Type of expression is ambiguous without more context) which looks impossible to find on Xcode. Looking into the code below, can you see what could possibly be wrong ? I already take a look into the web but this error is general and can appear on many situations without detail. I'm now using JSONDecoder instead of serialization as suggested into the comments but same issue. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

var locationManager = LocationManager()

var userLatitude: String {
    return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
}

var userLongitude: String {
    return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
}

// MARK: - WidgetData
struct WidgetData {
    let temperature: Double
    let feels: Double
    let humidity: Int
    let uvi: Double
    let conditionId: Int
    
    var conditionName: String {
        switch conditionId {
        case 200...232:
            return "cloud.bolt.rain"
        case 300...321:
            return "cloud.drizzle"
        case 500...531:
            return "cloud.rain"
        case 600...622:
            return "cloud.snow"
        case 701...780:
            return "cloud.fog"
        case 781:
            return "tornado"
        case 800:
            return "sun.max"
        case 801...804:
            return "cloud"
        default:
            return "cloud"
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - WeatherData
struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let current: Current
}

// MARK: - Current
struct Current: Decodable {
    let temp, feels_like: Double
    let humidity, uvi: Double
    let weather: [Weather]
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Decodable {
    let id: Int
}

struct WeatherLoader {
    
    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?exclude=minutely,hourly&units=metric&lat=\(userLatitude)&lon=\(userLongitude)") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (weatherData, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherData? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            
            let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            
            //Current Weather
            let temp = decodedData?.current.temp
            let feels_like = decodedData?.current.feels_like
            let humidity = decodedData?.current.humidity
            let uvi = decodedData?.current.uvi
            let id = decodedData?.current.weather[0].id

            let widgetData = WidgetData(temp: temp, feels_like: feels_like, humidity: humidity, uvi: uvi, conditionId: id)
            
            return widgetData
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The error points to the "W" into WidgetData(temp: ...

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: Not related to your question but you shouldn't declare your location manage globally

Comment: Btw Codable it is been around for a while already. It doesn't make any sense to use JSONSerialization jsonObject method anymore.

Comment: And looks like you have your own Data structure declared somewhere in your project. You better choose another name for it. Data is a Swift native type. Thats why the compiler is forcing you to type Foundation.Data when referring to it.

Comment: You are trying to initialise a `Current` object using a bunch of arrays and dictionaries but there is no such init method defined for `Current` hence the word "ambiguous" in the error message. The init method you are using expects a single value per parameter. Since I don't know the underlying data structure I have no idea what the right solution is here except as mentioned earlier that you should use `Codable` instead.

Comment: Changed code as suggested into the comments above but the issue persists, any idea ?